# Authentication Failure when connecting to Azurite

Tags: java, spring, azure, kotlin

I am using Azurite in docker-compose for local development. I have a simple application that talks to it using the Java Azure SDK. I am trying to connect using the default Azurite connection string `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==` but when I try and connect I get an Authentication error:

```
app      | RequestId:648770d1-301e-00a3-28d6-dcfab7000000
app      | Time:2020-02-06T10:19:10.6959018Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'vSVMXMpgTMISc9Fgx2bu0kg7uu0duhmdn6dllfc4r1g=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      | Thu, 06 Feb 2020 10:19:09 GMT
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      | x-ms-client-request-id:4bd883d4-229a-4dec-bf6f-221f3636dccf
app      | x-ms-version:2019-02-02
app      | /devstoreaccount1/
app      | comp:list'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Status code 403, "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
app      | RequestId:648770d1-301e-00a3-28d6-dcfab7000000
app      | Time:2020-02-06T10:19:10.6959018Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'vSVMXMpgTMISc9Fgx2bu0kg7uu0duhmdn6dllfc4r1g=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'GET
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      | Thu, 06 Feb 2020 10:19:09 GMT
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      |
app      | x-ms-client-request-id:4bd883d4-229a-4dec-bf6f-221f3636dccf
app      | x-ms-version:2019-02-02
app      | /devstoreaccount1/
app      | comp:list'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>"]
```

I am unsure what the issue and I have not found a solution online as yet. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

I am using the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
  <version>12.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and this is my simple Controller:

```
package com.sky.video.azuritedemo

import com.azure.core.http.rest.PagedIterable
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder
import com.azure.storage.blob.models.BlobContainerItem
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@RestController
class AzureController() {

  @GetMapping("/container")
  fun getContainers(): PagedIterable<BlobContainerItem>? {
    val connectionString = System.getenv("AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING")

    val client = BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .connectionString(connectionString)
        .buildClient()

    return client
        .listBlobContainers()
  }
}
```

And the env variable is set in docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    command: "mvn spring-boot:run"
    container_name: app
    depends_on:
      - azure
    environment:
      AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING: "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
    links:
      - azure
    ports:
      - 5005:5005
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ~/.m2:/root/.m2
      - .:/app
  azure:
    command: "azurite --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --queueHost 0.0.0.0  -d /tmp/logs/debug.log"
    container_name: azure
    environment:
      EXECUTABLE: blob
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "10001:10001"
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/tmp/logs
```

Further investigation shows that I get the same issue when I run both Azurite and my application directly on my local machine.

Comment: looks like the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615330/connecting-to-azurite-using-a-hostname-fails

Answer (score 3):

Please try to use the following connection string:

```
UseDevelopmentStorage=true
```

The above connection string will try to connect to default IP address (127.0.0.1) and ports (e.g. 10000 for blob storage).

If you use different IP address and ports, use the following connection string:

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;
AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;
BlobEndpoint=http://<ip-address>:<blob-port>/devstoreaccount1;
```

instead of

```
DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==
```

Comment: that doesn't work because it tries to connect to Azurite on 127.0.0.1, but as I am running in docker-compose that is not the IP address of the Azurite instance

Comment: What's the IP address of Azurite instance?

Comment: well as it's inside a docker network I don't know and I very much doubt it will be the same between restarts.

Comment: I think you would need to specify an IP address to connect to storage emulator. I have edited my answer and included an alternate connection string where you can specify an IP address and port.

Comment: even when I run both Azurite and my application on the host machine and connect using 127.0.0.1 I get the same error