# Connect to Azurite from .NET App via Docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, azurite

I have a .NET 6 API (running in Docker), and Azurite (running in Docker).

I'm trying to connect to Azurite from the .NET app using the .NET SDK, but am getting the following error in the Docker logs:

> System.AggregateException: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings
> can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (Connection refused
> (azurite:10000)) (Connection refused (azurite:10000)) (Connection
> refused (azurite:10000)) (Connection refused (azurite:10000))
> (Connection refused (azurite:10000)) (Connection refused
> (azurite:10000))

It's dying on this second line (`CreateIfNotExists()`):

```
_blobContainerClient = new BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerName);
_blobContainerClient.CreateIfNotExists();
```

Here's my connection string in my .NET app:

```
"Azure": {
        "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
    }
```

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    container_name: aft-backend-api
    build:
      context: src
      dockerfile: API/Dockerfile    
    networks:
      - aft-backend
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
      - Azure__StorageConnectionString=UseDevelopmentStorage=true;DevelopmentStorageProxyUri=http://azurite;
    depends_on:
      - azurite
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: aft-backend-azurite
    hostname: azurite
    restart: always
    command: 'azurite --blobHost 127.0.0.1 --blobPort 10000 --queueHost 127.0.0.1 --queuePort 10001'
    ports:
      - 10000:10000
      - 10001:10001
    networks:
      - aft-backend

networks:
  aft-backend:
    name: aft-backend-network
```

Things to note:

- I'm overriding the connection string in the compose file, by using the `environment` variable
- I've set the `DevelopmentStorageProxyUri` to the hostname (azurite)
- I'm using `depends_on` to ensure that Azurite starts up before the API

I noticed this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615330/connecting-to-azurite-using-a-hostname-fails), however it seems outdated and doesn't' have a clear answer.

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a hard time with this as well. At the end of the day, this is how I got it working:

`docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    command: "azurite --loose --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --location /workspace --debug /workspace/debug.log"
    ports:
      - 10010:10000
      - 10011:10001
      - 10012:10002
    volumes:
      - ./azurite:/workspace

  backend:
    build:
      context: backend
      args:
        AzureWebJobsStorage: "${AzureWebJobsStorage}"
    ports:
      - 10004:80
    depends_on:
      - azurite
```

Connection string used in the app: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://host.docker.internal:10010/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://host.docker.internal:10011/devstoreaccount1;`

I'm passing in the connection string with and env file, but it should work just as well in your `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Question: where does the `AccountKey` come from? Is that generated somehow for Azurite?

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/Azurite#connection-strings

Comment: Ah right, thanks! Your solution worked great, thanks! I had to tweak a little, but it got me on the right track. I'll post my answer to help others, but ill accept yours. Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Got it working with the help of @peinearydevelopment's answer.

I had to change my `docker-compose` file to:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}api
    container_name: aft-backend-api
    build:
      context: src
      dockerfile: API/Dockerfile    
    networks:
      - aft-backend
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
      - Azure__StorageConnectionString=DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://host.docker.internal:10000/devstoreaccount1;QueueEndpoint=http://host.docker.internal:10001/devstoreaccount1;
    depends_on:
      - azurite
  azurite:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-storage/azurite
    container_name: aft-backend-azurite
    hostname: azurite
    restart: always
    command: 'azurite --loose --blobHost 0.0.0.0 --blobPort 10000 --queueHost 0.0.0.0 --queuePort 10001 --location /workspace --debug /workspace/debug.log'
    ports:
      - 10000:10000
      - 10001:10001
    volumes:
      - ./azurite:/workspace
    networks:
      - aft-backend

networks:
  aft-backend:
    name: aft-backend-network
```

The main thing was using the proper Azure Connection String, and making sure the ports matched up to what was being set in the azurite command.

Comment: I had to add this as well <br/>

`extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
`<br/>
... as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324981/how-to-access-host-port-from-docker-container